# Override and rename Entity Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using ef and my model inherit from : Entity.
Like this, my Id will be model.Id.
So I wanna rename it in the model and in the database to become model.Model_Id. Anyway?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly. [Try something like this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: It's obviously not possible to change the name of a property that is inherited from a parent class, that would break the contract. What you can do if you want is to create a `public int Model_Id { get => Id; set => Id = value }` property

Comment: Just use `[Key]` annotation on the property you want, so that will be used as a key

Comment: Where is this "this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default of using your entity class property name to a different database column name like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
     
    [Column("Name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}
```

In the above StudentName will be mapped to a column "Name" in the database.  You should be able to take the same approach to rename Id to Model_Id.

But, as mentioned by others you cannot 'rename' a base class property with a different name.  One option you could test out would be:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   [NotMapped]
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass
{
    public int Model_Id
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Id = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, EF will map Model_Id to the database.  But not map Id to the database.